# Creating a dynamic .htaccess for a Vue app

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am currently building a Vue app which requires a .htaccess which includes the subdirectory (`publicPath`) that the app will be installed in.

Is there a 'builtin' way to create `.htaccess` in `public/` or `assets/` that is updated to include `publicPath`?

I've looked at the `HtmlWebpackPlugin` template handling of `index.html`, but this doesn't seem to have the option to modify other files.

Otherwise I guess I can run some custom JS as part of the build process.